# Is there a site that loads slowly on purpose?

Tags: testing, web

I'm working on the system that embeds a browser object. One of the requirements is to put a "Please wait" message if the page takes too long to load.

If there a site out there that deliberately loads slowly for the purpose of testing?

I don't care what the content is, I just want it to make 5+ seconds to load.

Comment: any myspace page comes to mind. Assuming they're still around

Answer (score 1):

You can try below site

http://www.zaads.net/[1](http://www.zaads.net/)

It is almost 9 times slower than your requirement.[image]